# Find prime p for which $5 k^2+k(10n-13)-7n+6=5^p$ has no natural solution.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Consider $k$ and $n$ , two natural numbers. What are the values of $p$ for which $$5 k^2+k(10n-13)-7n+6=5^p$$ has only non-natural solutions?